# How to get substring from particular pattern

Tags: powershell

I have an array of string values like `$dirSourceFolder = "$DeliveryStore\BBG\Port"`. From here I just want to extract BBG.

We can have different values like `$directoryServices = "$DeliveryStore\BBG", $ddS ="$DeliveryStore\BBG\Port\Function\CDE"` but `$DeliveryStore\` will always be common.

Also in every case I just need BBG.

I've tried this using IndexOf but I am not able to get results. Please assist.

Comment: Please _edit the question_ and explain with more details what you are looking for. Extracting `BBG` only makes no sense, you already have it as a constant. Are you looking `BBG` and everything after that?

Comment: I have already written PS which gives me output into an array and above values are the results that are stored in an array and from the above I only need to extract BBG value as those are folder names and $DeliveryStore\ is the base location.

Answer (score 1):

This may work:

```
($dirSourceFolder -split "\\")[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also play around with Regex:

```
$substring = if ($dirSourceFolder -match '\\?(BBG)\\?') { $matches[1] }
```

Or (Case Sensitive)

```
$substring = [regex]::Match($dirSourceFolder, '\\?(BBG)\\?').Groups[1].Value
```

Or same as the above, but now Case-Insensitive

```
$caseInsensitive = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase
$substring = [regex]::Match($dirSourceFolder, '\\?(bbg)\\?', $caseInsensitive).Groups[1].Value
```

All will output

> BBG

P.S. using `IndexOf` would also work, but takes more effort:

```
$index = $dirSourceFolder.IndexOf('\BBG\')  #'# include the backslashes
if ($index -ge 0) { 
    $substring = $dirSourceFolder.Substring($index + 1, 'BBG'.Length)
}
```